# What is meant by the "angle" that the variety makes with a boundary of a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry

I am reading an article and I am very confused at the following part. It states that: at each point $\mathbf{x}$ of the boundary $\partial D$ (here $D$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ bounded by planes parallel to the co-ordinate hyperplanes),  the variety $V(F)$ makes a positive angle with $\partial D$. Here $V(F)$ is the zero set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ of homogeneous polynomial $F$.

Could someone please explain to me what is meant by "(positive) angle"? Any comments and explanations are appreciated. Thank you very much.